# How to rearrange WordPress REST API comments?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, reactjs, api

I am using React and WordPress API. I get the comments of a post with a parent attribute, but they are not organised as a threaded comments. 
Comments can be obviously parents and children. 
I need to display them as threaded comments, any idea how to achieve this?

Is there a way to?

These are the comments I get in the console:
[image]

Comment: Is `parent` the id of the parent?

Comment: yes it is the id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code does what you want. It sorts the list by descending order of parent id, and pushes each comment to the children of the parent. If the parent is 0, it will not push it, since that must be one of the first comments.

```js
var arr = [
    {id: 7, post: 1, parent: 4, author: 1, author_name: 'me'},
    {id: 6, post: 1, parent: 5, author: 1, author_name: 'me'},
    {id: 5, post: 1, parent: 4, author: 1, author_name: 'me'},
    {id: 4, post: 1, parent: 0, author: 1, author_name: 'me'},
    {id: 3, post: 1, parent: 0, author: 1, author_name: 'me'},
    {id: 2, post: 1, parent: 1, author: 1, author_name: 'me'},
    {id: 1, post: 1, parent: 0, author: 0, author_name: 'other'},
]

arr = arr.sort((a, b) => b.parent - a.parent)

const sortComments = (arr) => {
    var temp = [...arr]
    arr.forEach((o, index) => {
        if (temp[0].parent === 0) return
        var parentIndex = temp.findIndex(o => o.id === temp[0].parent)
        temp[parentIndex].children ? temp[parentIndex].children.push(temp[0]) : temp[parentIndex].children = [temp[0]]
        temp.shift()
    })

    return temp
}

console.log(sortComments(arr))
```

Comment: hey, this only work partially: when i have 2 sub comments one is a child/parent that has another child comments, it just add the number 2 as children. i don't know how to add an image of the console to this comment so you can see it.

Comment: @Ron I fixed that now, try again. I was returning the `push` length, not the actual array.

Comment: ho there was a change so wait

Comment: it is almost there. now if a parent comment has 2 , but one is a child and the other is a grandchild, it push the child twice,

Comment: @Ron Ill fix that now

Comment: @Ron try now :)

Comment: now i get like 10 children where it should be 2, one child and one grandchild

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195110/discussion-between-kobe-and-ron).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `order` and `orderby` parameters. Check wp rest api [handboook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/comments/).